# How to split the dataset into train/ validation / test with cvpartion?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, cross-validation

I'm training NNs for classification. However, I only have 525 samples and approximately 300 predictor variables. I know I could try to reduce the number of variables, looking for the ones that are really more important, but this is not the point.

Currently I divide my data into training / validation / test, using validation for early stop during network training.

I want to use cross-validation in Matlab with the **cvpartition function**, however this function divides dataset in training / test. Is there any way to use cvpartition to split into training / validation / test?

```
c=cvpartition(t_class,'KFold',10,'Stratify', true)

K-fold cross validation partition
   NumObservations: 525
       NumTestSets: 10
         TrainSize: 473  472  472  472  472  472  473  473  473  473
          TestSize: 52  53  53  53  53  53  52  52  52  52
```

Answer (score 3):

Coss-validation is only meant to have two sets, the one it is training on and the other it tests on and in the next iteration again. So `cvpartition` won't give you a split into three sets. You can now argue that the validation set os only a subset of the test set, so you use `cvpartition` again on this, making sure that you do not accidentally test on the whole test set (this doesn't work for corss-validation) **or** if you want to apply cross-validation, do it the other way around:

```
% 20% for validation
cvp = cvpartition(t_class,'HoldOut',0.2);
% extract the data set
t_class_Val = t_class(cvp.test);
% Dat_Val     = Dat(cvp.test,:);

t_class_TrnTst  = t_class(cvp.training);
% Dat_TrnTst      = Dat(cvp.training,:);

% cross-validation for the rest
cvp2 = cvpartition(t_class_TrnTst,'KFold',10,'Stratify', true);
```

The other option is to code it yourself. You can randomize indices with `randperm`.